# Hapi 17: Expose server properies to module registration

Tags: hapi.js

We're upgrading our Hapi 16 application to Hapi 17, and Hapi-Mysql-2, and have encountered a problem with accessing server properties when a module is registered.

Hapi-mysql-2 exposes registered database servers as `server.mysql.pool[x]` which we are exposing as `req.server.plugin.db.name`

Whilst in most cases this way of accessing the databases is fine there are a couple of cases where we want to access the database as soon as the module is registered. However, in these cases neither `req` or `server` are avaialble.

For example

```
async function loadAllGroups (mydb) {
  const sql = 'SELECT * ' +
    'FROM groups ' +
    'ORDER BY name ASC;'
  const [data] = await mydb.query(sql, [])
  return data
}    

loadAllGroups(req.server.plugins.dbs.name)

  .then((data) => {
    setGroups(data)
  })

module.exports = new MyController()
```

In the above `loadAllGroups` is invoked as soon as the `mycontroller` is registered as a handler in my routed. In the Hapi 16 version the mysql server is not hooked to `server` so we can call it any time after it has been registered.

Any thoughts / solutions?

Comment: Have you taken a look at using the [`pre`](https://hapijs.com/api#-routeoptionspre) route option as way of injecting dependencies into your controller?

Comment: We're using pre for some of our Authentication. This was a case where the old backend was caching a set of data as soon as it started - i.e. as soon as the Database Plugin was being registered. That data was then being used used as part of one of the pre checks.

I've rewritten to load the data the first time the pre function is called, but the question is still I think a valid one.